# How to exclude a particular crate-type from build?

Tags: android, rust, rust-cargo, hyper, reqwest

My Rust project depends on crate `reqwest` which depends on `hyper`.

When I build my project for Android platform

```
cargo.exe build --target aarch64-linux-android
```

`cargo` cannot find `cc`.

```
   Compiling hyper v0.14.4
error: linker `cc` not found

= note: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)

error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile `hyper`.
```

If I remove the following lines from `hyper`'s `Cargo.toml`

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["lib", "staticlib", "cdylib"]
```

then I can build my project without problems.

How can I build my project without modifying `hyper`'s `Cargo.toml`? How exclude its `staticlib` and `cdylib` crate types from the build?

**SOLUTION / WORKAROUND**

I found a solution/workaround for my issue. I've added to `.cargo/config`:

```
[target.aarch64-linux-android]
linker = 'aarch64-linux-android28-clang.cmd'
```

Now `hyper` is compiled as `lib`, `staticlib` and `cdylib`. And by the way, it was the `cdylib` crate type who wanted `cc`.

Comment: I think this is related to that: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/4881

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION / WORKAROUND**

I found a solution/workaround for my issue. I've added to `.cargo/config`:

```
[target.aarch64-linux-android]
linker = 'aarch64-linux-android28-clang.cmd'
```

Now `hyper` is compiled as `lib`, `staticlib` and `cdylib`. And by the way, it was the `cdylib` crate type who wanted `cc`.